# How to generate real UTF-8 XML with grails without the escape characters?

Tags: xml, grails, utf-8, escaping, character-reference

I have been wondering why when I set the encoding to UTF-8 and rendering the XML it replace the extended characters by escape characters (or character reference) like &#x2019; instead of '?

I'm using the Render method

```
render(contentType:"text/xml", encoding:"UTF-8") {...}
```

with a proper header

```
render(contentType:"text/xml", encoding:"UTF-8", text:"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n")
```

Any idea if there is a way to write it properly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have anything set in `Config.groovy` like `grails.converters.encoding`? What is it set to?

Comment: I think it's set properly: grails.converters.encoding="UTF-8"